# Git for developing on 2 sites

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I have two locations from which I develop (in different countries). Using VS2019 and its Git facilities. I would like to use the Git remote so that on reaching a second location, I can update the local repository for a project to exactly match where I finished on the first, so that I can continue its development.

If the project does not yet exist in the second location, the clone is straightforward. However, if it exists - typically several versions behind - I am unsure how to safely update this to the latest without danger of affecting the remote. I tried sync and pull, which left the local repository in a mess, so I chickened out and copied the project from a USB stick - and back again when I returned to loc 1 - far from ideal.

I have not branched the project, operating solely on the master. Should I be branching the project in location 2 and then merge it back somehow when returning to location 1?

Apologies for such a naive question - it is probably such a usual scenario - office/home - that the answer is obvious. However, I can't find a straightforward explanation (ideally using the VS2019 UI).

Can someone please help (or point me to a step-by-step explanation)?

Comment: I don't use VS (any version) and it might obfuscate this and/or make it hard or impossible to *use*, but as far as Git goes, every repository is its own king; all other repositories are mere peons. Nobody can do anything *to* you unless *you* give them access (e.g., via ssh or http/https). So you can do whatever you like locally; nobody else can even *see* it, much less do anything with it, unless you let them (i.e., yourself from some other machine) log in via ssh or https and `git fetch` new commits.

Comment: If you're sitting in Location 1 and are using Git there, that's *the* repository. Everything else is just some random junk, unless you, at Location 1, command your Git to use it. If you now move over to Location 2 and are using (another) Git there (on another repository), that's *the* repository. That thing over at Location 1? Some random junk, unless you, at Location 2, command your Git to use it.

Comment: As long as the way you, sitting wherever you are sitting, command your Git to do things is with `git fetch`, you'll just get any new commits *from* "them" / "their repository" (whoever that might be—ok, it was yourself last week, but hey, we don't know THAT guy do we? :-) ) that you don't already have here in *your* repository. That will update the remote-tracking names under the name of the remote you use to access the other Git repository.

Comment: The wrinkle here—the fly in the ointment, as it were—is `git push`: with `git push`, you give your commits, from your Git repository, to some other Git repository. So far that's fine: we're just adding commits, so nothing is *lost*, only *gained*. But then at the last step of `git push` we ask or command *their* Git to set some of *their* branch names. Since branch names are the main way we *find* commits, if they set their branch names as we suggest, we may make it impossible for them to find their own earlier commits. If "they" are just "us next week", then next week when we go there...

Comment: ... when we go there and become "them", we may not be able to find our own commits, because that jerk (who was us a week ago) told us to overwrite the commit-finding information. So either be *careful* with `git push`, or just don't ever *use* `git push`. Use `git fetch` and there's no problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments but I am afraid I am not clear which you are referring to as between the local 'repository' (ie on the local PC) and the remote GitHub 'repository'. I am also a little confused over your 4th para Git push setting branch names. If I have pushed a new commit from Location 2 to the master created in Location 1, how are branch names affected? Sorry to be dim.

Comment: Hm, well, I'm not sure exactly where your thinking doesn't match what Git actually does. The key notion is that Git literally shares *commits* but not *branch names*, when you connect one Git to another. You send or receive commits, and now you and they (whoever "you" and "they" are **at this moment in time** - this moves around when *you* move around, but you're always typing commands at some Git repository, to punch in a `git fetch` or a `git push` command) share *commits* but not *branch names*.

Comment: It's `git push` that's weird here, because when you use `git push` from your Git, you first send them any commits they'll need, then you ask or command them to set one of their *branch names*. So that's when you affect *someone else's* branch names. But "you" is always "the Git repository at which you're typing `git push` or `git fetch`" here.

Answer (score -1):

First off, you are using GIT.  Awesome! I commend you.
torek has some great comments, and I felt all of those would have made a better solution.  But I felt your question deserved an answer.

First Branches are awesome.  I would recommend creating a branch.
[image: NewBranchMenu]
[image: Based on Master]

The "Checkout Branch" will make sure the working copy is that branch.
Do some edits.
[image: SampleCommit]

Now we have a Master (old code) and Working Branch (current code).
Lets practice a merge without risking destorying master.
So create a new "MergeTestBranch" based on master.

[image: MakeSureItsBasedOnMaster]
You have a choice to base the new branch on master or any other branch.  Check this out.  This is a "new" master.

Select GIT->ManageBranches
[image: Magage Branch]
[image: MergeOption]
If you right mouse over the latest branch you have an option to "Merge" those changes into MergeTestBranch now.  This will allow you to test the Merge process without messing up the master branch.

I don't have examples currently setup to show fetch/push.
But if you are working in a unique branch name, then when you fetch it will not clobber master at all, it will just create a new branch or tracking branch.  So working in branches gives you a bit more safety, and you only "merge into master" when eveything checks out.  When working on multiple nodes in different countries I would "push" if I wasn't sure I would have abiltiy to "fetch" later.... but then I would typically make sure I had a different branch name on each site.
That way I could keep track of where the changes were.

Comment: Ross, thanks for your extensive explanation, It seems a safe, clear and relatively straightforward way to achieve the objective. But why has somebody marked it down, anonymously, without any explanation at all? Is there some flaw in the logic?

Comment: My experience level with GIT is maybe 6 weeks ahead of you.  I've been forcing myself to use/learn it over the past year, but I am by no means an expert.  Most of my development work is solo, and my customers use SVN, so when I work in teams I'm typically committing in SVN.  Our company uses GIT but my work is customer focused, so I don't get a lot of practial GIT experience other than doing work very similar to what you describe where my locally managed GIT repos are distributed on machines in different parts of the word prior to my committing to SVN.